# How to view phppgadmin as the application name in PostgreSQL's log files?

Tags: postgresql, log, phppgadmin

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.2 (Windows) with phpPgAdmin 5.1.

I need to monitor who connects to the server, and with which application.

In the logging parameters of postgresql.conf, I use the following log line prefix:

```
log_line_prefix = '%t\t%a\t%d\t%h\t%u\t'
```

where `%a` specifies the application connected to the database.

Once a user is connected to the server using **psql** and executes a command, it shows in the log as follows:

```
2016-03-14 14:55:11 EDT psql    phenotree_development   000.000.000.00  cleseb  LOG:  duration: 32.000 ms  statement: select * from organisms limit 10;
```

However, when **PhpPgAdmin** is used, the application name never shows, for example:

```
2016-03-17 09:30:30 EDT [unknown]   phenotree_development   ::1 cleseb  LOG:  duration: 0.000 ms  statement: SELECT * FROM (select * from organisms) AS sub  LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

How to have the application name appear in the log for PhpPgAdmin?

Comment: I'd try to specify the application name in `config.inc.php`, in the relevant $conf['servers'] array.  The parameter to `libpq` is `application_name`, try this one.  You will have to reconnect to see if it works.

Comment: I added this line to `config.inc.php`, but it doesn't seem to work after phpPgAdmin logout/login: `$conf['servers'][0]['application_name'] = 'phppga';`

Comment: Another idea is setting the `PGAPPNAME` environmental variable: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-APPLICATION-NAME